# Stream to Apple TV?

Tags: sound, video, streaming, media

I would like to be able to do AV streaming and (or) mirroring with my apple TV from Ubuntu. I'm running 13.04. Is this possible, or will I have to do the outrageously inconvenient task of using an $20 HDMI cable (`</sarcasm>`)?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, AppleTV is pretty much a closed ecosystem. Content from any computers on the network is drawn from iTunes Libraries. There are some systems like the Synology NAS boxes that support hosting iTunes libraries, and could possibly act as a media server for an AppleTV, but I don't have a Synology box to test that out. Given that the Synology boxes are running a Linux-derived OS, there may be software out there that would allow Ubuntu/Linux to act as a media server for AppleTV but I have not found it yet.

Comment: Well, I know for a fact you can stream from a Google Nexus 4 using ZappoTV, so there must be someway to access it.

Comment: @JShoe - yes, there are workarounds that enable streaming via Airplay, but I have found nothing for getting non-Airplay sources to show in the ATV interface. Personally, I'm looking to set up a Raspberry Pi with XBMC to be a media server for my HDTV and that would allow connection to my non-Apple media libraries.

Comment: I hear ya. Honestly, I'm just not that familiar with media centers in general.